# Checking tarfile integrity in Python

Tags: python, error-handling, integrity, tarfile

I'm working on converting my backup script from shell to Python. One of the features of my old script was to check the created tarfile for integrity by doing: gzip -t .

This seems to be a bit tricky in Python.

It seems that the only way to do this, is by reading each of the compressed TarInfo objects within the tarfile.

Is there a way to check a tarfile for integrity, without extracting to disk, or keeping it in memory (in it's entirety)?

Good people on #python on freenode suggested that I should read each TarInfo object chunk-by-chunk, discarding each chunk read.

I must admit that I have no idea how to do this, seeing that I just started Python.

Imagine that I have a tarfile of 30GB which contains files ranging from 1kb to 10GB...

This is the solution that I started writing:

```
try:
    tardude = tarfile.open("zero.tar.gz")
except:
    print "There was an error opening tarfile. The file might be corrupt or missing."

for member_info in tardude.getmembers():
    try:
        check = tardude.extractfile(member_info.name)
    except:
        print "File: %r is corrupt." % member_info.name

tardude.close()
```

This code is far from finished. I would not dare running this on a huge 30GB tar archive, because at one point, check would be an object of 10+GB (If i have such huge files within the tar archive)

Bonus:
I tried manually corrupting zero.tar.gz (hex editor - edit a few bytes midfile). The first except does not catch IOError... Here is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 31, in <module>
    for member_info in tardude.getmembers():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1805, in getmembers
    self._load()        # all members, we first have to
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 2380, in _load
    tarinfo = self.next()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 2315, in next
    self.fileobj.seek(self.offset)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 429, in seek
    self.read(1024)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 256, in read
    self._read(readsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 320, in _read
    self._read_eof()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 342, in _read_eof
    hex(self.crc)))
IOError: CRC check failed 0xe5384b87 != 0xdfe91e1L
```

Comment: I've tried the tarfile module with a LOT of files, the thing is that tarfile.TarFile module stores all read(or wrote) members into it's "members". So it'll take a lot of memory when you intentionally read a tarbomb with lots, lots of small files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a minor improvement on [Aya's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172176/aya) answer to make things a little more idiomatic (although I'm removing some of the error checking to make the mechanics more visible):

```
BLOCK_SIZE = 1024

with tarfile.open("zero.tar.gz") as tardude:
    for member in tardude.getmembers():
        with tardude.extractfile(member.name) as target:
            for chunk in iter(lambda: target.read(BLOCK_SIZE), b''):
                pass
```

This really just removes the `while 1:` (sometimes considered a minor code smell) and the `if not data:` check. Also note that the use of `with` restricts this to Python 2.7+

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `subprocess` module to call `gzip -t` on the file...

```
from subprocess import call
import os

with open(os.devnull, 'w') as bb:
    result = call(['gzip', '-t', "zero.tar.gz"], stdout=bb, stderr=bb)
```

If `result` is not 0, something is amiss. You might want to check if gzip is available, though. I wrote a utility function for that;

```
import subprocess
import sys
import os

def checkfor(args, rv = 0):
    """Make sure that a program necessary for using this script is
    available.

    Arguments:
    args  -- string or list of strings of commands. A single string may
             not contain spaces.
    rv    -- expected return value from evoking the command.
    """
    if isinstance(args, str):
        if ' ' in args:
            raise ValueError('no spaces in single command allowed')
        args = [args]
    try:
        with open(os.devnull, 'w') as bb:
            rc = subprocess.call(args, stdout=bb, stderr=bb)
        if rc != rv:
            raise OSError
    except OSError as oops:
        outs = "Required program '{}' not found: {}."
        print(outs.format(args[0], oops.strerror))
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I want to use a pythonic approach, without resorting to subprocess. Thank you for your answer, though!

Answer (score 1):

> I tried manually corrupting zero.tar.gz (hex editor - edit a few bytes
>   midfile). The first except does not catch IOError...

If you look at the traceback, you'll see it's being thrown when you call `tardude.getmembers()`, so you'll need something like...

```
try:
    tardude = tarfile.open("zero.tar.gz")
except:
    print "There was an error opening tarfile. The file might be corrupt or missing."

try:
    members = tardude.getmembers()
except:
    print "There was an error reading tarfile members."

for member_info in members:
    try:
        check = tardude.extractfile(member_info.name)
    except:
        print "File: %r is corrupt." % member_info.name

tardude.close()
```

As for the original problem, you're almost there. You just need to read the data from your `check` object with something like...

```
BLOCK_SIZE = 1024

try:
    tardude = tarfile.open("zero.tar.gz")
except:
    print "There was an error opening tarfile. The file might be corrupt or missing."

try:
    members = tardude.getmembers()
except:
    print "There was an error reading tarfile members."

for member_info in members:
    try:            
        check = tardude.extractfile(member_info.name)
        while 1:
            data = check.read(BLOCK_SIZE)
            if not data:
                break
    except:
        print "File: %r is corrupt." % member_info.name

tardude.close()
```

...which should ensure you never use more than `BLOCK_SIZE` bytes of memory at a time.

Also, you should try to avoid using...

```
try:
    do_something()
except:
    do_something_else()
```

...because it will mask unexpected exceptions. Try to only catch the exception you actually intend to handle, like...

```
try:
    do_something()
except IOError:
    do_something_else()
```

...otherwise you'll find it more difficult to detect bugs in your code.

Comment: O great! Regading the "except:" stuff... I know about that... I usually have "except this:" "except that:"... "except:", but this was just for testing :D

Comment: I have done the following: http://pastie.org/7585277. As you can see, there is a check member_info.isfile, because parsing directories always gives an error. I would also like to skip parsing anything but plain files.

Comment: You'll need to check the `member_info` object inside the for-loop. Something like `if not member_info.isfile(): continue` ought to work.

Comment: This kinda helped, but also didn't (due to the Except: and tarfile issues, could you please edit them out of the code examples above?):
I **still** got bad tars to pass this test - the **only** way to make sure the tar is correct is by calling `tardude.extractall("/some/tmp/dir")`